# Setting ui:param conditionally

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, facelets

I want to set a ui:param depending on a bean value and I thought using c:if was a good idea. So I put in my page the following code:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:wai="http://www.id.ethz.ch/wai/jsf"
    template="/view/listView.xhtml">

        <c:if test="#{subscriptionListController.model.listViewName eq 'mySubscriptions'}">
         <ui:param name="title" value="#{msg.subscriptionTitleMySubscriptions}"/>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="#{subscriptionListController.model.listViewName eq 'paidSubscriptions'}">
         <ui:param name="title" value="#{msg.subscriptionTitlePaidSubscriptions}"/>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="#{subscriptionListController.model.listViewName eq 'allSubscriptions'}">
         <ui:param name="title" value="#{msg.subscriptionTitleAllSubscriptions}"/>
        </c:if>
        ....
```

but the parameter is not set...

If I let print out the value of `#{subscriptionListController.model.listViewName eq 'mySubscriptions'}` I get true in the corresponding case and false in the other two cases.

At the beginning I had only 2 possibilities and solved it with the ternary operator:

```
<ui:param name="title" value="#{subscriptionListController.model.listViewName eq 'mySubscriptions' ? msg.subscriptionTitleMySubscriptions : msg.subscriptionTitlePaidSubscriptions}"/>
```

and it worked. But now I have more possibilities...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not clear on when exactly it works/fails. The `<c:if>`s look fine, but `<c:otherwise>` is completely misplaced. It belongs in a `<c:choose>`. Also the code seems to be incomplete, this appears to be a template client, but I'm nowhere seeing an `<ui:define>`. You do know that anything outside `<ui:define>` and `<ui:composition>` is ignored by Facelets?

Comment: The `<ui:composition>` is there (see the first row of the code) so it shouldn't be ignored. I removed the `<c:otherwise>` and added a `c:if` instead. but it still doesn't work... As said, with the ternary operator no-problems, but with the `c:if` nope... (I edited my code, as the value for the title was wrong)

Comment: @ BalusC Ok, the `<ui:define>` is defined below. I shifted the `c:if`code there and now it works! But can you now explain me why with the tern. op. works although it is outside the `<ui:define>`? Besides I have others `ui:param` defined outside it (just below the `c:if`) and they work...

Comment: @BalusC Can you please put your comment into an answer, so that I can accept it, please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As indicated by `<ui:composition template>`, this page represents a template client.

Any `<ui:param>` outside `<ui:define>` applies to the master template (the file which you declared in `template` attribute) and is ignored inside the template client itself. If you intend to prepare variables for inside the template client, you should put `<ui:param>` inside `<ui:define>`.

But there's another thing: the original purpose of `<ui:param>` is to pass variables to the file referenced by `<ui:composition template>`, `<ui:decorate template>` or `<ui:include src>`, not to prepare/set variables inside the current facelet context. For the sole functional requirement of preparing/setting variables in the current EL context, you'd better be using JSTL `<c:set>` for the job. You *can* use `<ui:param>` for this, but this isn't its original intent and didn't work that way in older MyFaces versions.

Thus, so:

```
<ui:define>
    <c:if test="#{subscriptionListController.model.listViewName eq 'mySubscriptions'}">
        <c:set var="title" value="#{msg.subscriptionTitleMySubscriptions}"/>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="#{subscriptionListController.model.listViewName eq 'paidSubscriptions'}">
        <c:set var="title" value="#{msg.subscriptionTitlePaidSubscriptions}"/>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="#{subscriptionListController.model.listViewName eq 'allSubscriptions'}">
        <c:set var="title" value="#{msg.subscriptionTitleAllSubscriptions}"/>
    </c:if>
    ...
</ui:define>
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you can optimize this as follows without the need for an unmaintainable `<c:if>` group which would only grow with every subscription type:

```
<ui:define>
    <c:set var="subscriptionTitleKey" value="subscriptionTitle.#{subscriptionListController.model.listViewName}">
    <c:set var="title" value="#{msg[subscriptionTitleKey]}"/>
    ...
</ui:define>
```

with those keys

```
subscriptionTitle.mySubscriptions = Title for my subscriptions
subscriptionTitle.paidSubscriptions = Title for paid subscriptions
subscriptionTitle.allSubscriptions = Title for all subscriptions
```

Comment: "... is in turn technically wrong and works in Mojarra only, but not in MyFaces ..." That's not true. Instead, it is the opposite. It is a looooonnngggg story, but I have written the reasons in [MYFACES-3169](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-3169). Recently in [MYFACES-3810](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-3810) it was added in 2.2.x branch a flag to enable the old behavior. ui:param only works if is a direct child of ui:include, ui:decorate or ui:composition but the params are available in the context of the target template. Use them inside c:if is a bad idea.

Comment: @lu: by the way I also agree that we should really keep the `<c:set>`. Its ability to store the evaluated value in a fixed scope (request/view/session/application) is very appreciated. The `<ui:param>` doesn't support it (expression is re-evaluated on every access) and also the tag name "param" is at its own not really self-documenting as to the functional requirement of "setting a variable in the EL context".

Comment: absolutely, c:set is indeed very useful. What we did in MyFaces was fix c:set to use page scope when no scope is set like in JSP and create a "template context" to store ui:param variables. Both c:set and ui:param still relies on EL VariableMapper facility and are considered build view time tags. Without this fix, some optimizations like EL caching cannot be done properly. Really ui:param is a tag used to pass a parameter as an EL Expression to the template.

Answer (score 2):

You are using JSTL with Facelets. JSTL are executed during view build time, and not in render phase. Additionally there some issues with processing them in JSF2 libraries - like in older Mojarra versions, where they didn't work on view scoped beans with partial state saving - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3343681). This is why your EL expression has worked.

The solution is to avoid JSTL - use ui:repeat instead c:forEach and EL expression and conditional rendering instead of c:if.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, but how can I use conditional rendering with ui:param?

Comment: @Francesco primefaces components, as well as ui:fragment have 'rendered' attribute, which takes EL expression.

Comment: Ok, I see the ui:param has the rendered attribute too (I didn't thought...)

Comment: Mmm, now I have `<ui:param name="title" value="#{msg.subscriptionTitleMySubscriptions}" rendered="#{subscriptionListController.model.listViewName eq 'mySubscriptions'}"/>` (three times for the different possibilities), but it doesn't work. Now the last of the three is always choosen...

Comment: I also tried to specify **true**, **false**, **false** instead of the checking EL, but although the last is false, it is the one which is "rendered"

Comment: @Francesco ui:param doesn't have rendered attribute. General advice: if you need to have more complicated expression in EL, consider creating a method in bean that would return what you need.

Comment: I tried with `<ui:fragment rendered="#{subscriptionListController.model.listViewName eq 'mySubscriptions'}">
  <ui:param name="title" value="msg.subscriptionTitleMySubscriptions" rendered="#{subscriptionListController.model.listViewName eq 'mySubscriptions'}"/>
 </ui:fragment>` but it doesn't work too... Sorry but now I don't have any other ideas/jsf-knowledge to solve the problem using your tip to use EL and cond. rendering to replace c:if...

Comment: I will remove the downvote if you explain "many bugs" in detail. Usually, those are namely just developer's own mistakes/misunderstandings. In the meanwhile, perhaps you want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense first.

Comment: @BalusC Sorry BalusC, but I don't understand what do you mean with the first two sentences.

Comment: Comment is targeted on answer of web devie not on your question.

Comment: @BalusC actually, I've seen that post, well, maybe it's not a bug but issue, anyway I've seen also somewhere in your answer that you've opted against using JSTL.

Comment: @BalusC Ah, ok :) Any tip on how to solve the problem? What I need is really just a way to choose between three possibilities... :(

Comment: Just start giving feedback on my comment on your question.

Comment: @BalusC One think is not clear to me... In your answer(the linked one) you said `...The view build time is that moment when the XHTML/JSP file is to be parsed and converted to a JSF component tree ...` and then `Use JSTL tags to control flow of JSF component tree building...`. But what I did in my (original) question is not that? The `c:if` doesn't "control/say" which of the three possibilities should be in the JSF component tree?

Comment: I didn't mean to give feedback on my comment on this answer, but on your own question. Scroll back to top to your question. Look at the bottom of your question. There's a comment on that. Give feedback to that. All comments on a certain post are targeted on the poster of that post, not to someone else.